# Visio 2010 forward engineering to Oracle 10g xe

Tags: oracle, plugins, visio, forward-engineer

I've been googleing  but maybe I'm not using the right words, so:
I have a ER diagram made in Visio 2010, and I what to do a forward engineering to an Oracle database.

I've found a forward engineering [plugin for Visio 2010](http://forwardengineer.codeplex.com/)  but this generates a MS SQL Server script, and the diagram has lots of tables, so editing the script is a last resort.

Can you please recommend me a tool/plugin, that can somehow make the Visio 2010 diagram in script for Oracle or a MS Sql Server to Oracle converter or some tool that can generate Oracle script from the Visio 2010 supported export formats (.vsd, .vdw, .vdx, .dwg, .dxf ...) ?

Thanks

Comment: If your target database is Oracle, why not use a modelling tool which supports forward engineering to that DBMS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one path that should work but may be a little fiddly: use Oracle's SQL Developer Data Modeler tool.  It's free.  [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html).

You can import your SQL Server DDL into Data Modeler. The import process certainly isn't perfect so you'll probably need to do some tweaking of the model. From Data Modeler you can forward engineer Oracle DDL.